# Express route ('begin-url-(type:string2|string3)?-end-url')?

Tags: reactjs, express, routes

Hello I have these routes:

```
router.route('/begin-url-presaved-:param').get(Controller.method1)
router.route('/begin-url-postsaved-:param').get(Controller.method2)
router.route('/begin-url-:param').get(Controller.method3)
```

Examples of urls:

```
/begin-url-presaved-param001   (type: presaved, param: param001)
/begin-url-postsaved-param001  (type: postsaved, param: param001)
/begin-url-param001            (type: null, param: param001)
```

There is any method to group these urls, so them will call the same controller, **then I will have only one route and only one controller**.
like this...

```
router.route('/begin-url-:type(presaved|postsaved)?-:param').get(Controller.method)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You cannot. the router has no way of knowing that param001 isn't actually a type. If you wanted to do it, the following, param001 should be be passed as a get query, so your route would be router.route('/begin-url-:param/?prepost=value).get(...)

Comment: thanks! but I need to manage the 3 urls (from examples) >_<, so they must maintain the sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
router.get('/begin-url:type(-presaved|-postsaved)?-:param', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.params);
});
```

It doesn't quite give you what you want because the `type` will have the hyphen at the start but I imagine that won't be a problem. It is possible to get rid of that hyphen in the `type` by tweaking the path but I couldn't find a way to do it that is compatible with both Express 4 and Express 5 routes, so I settled for leaving it in.